# adb install stuck in docker container

Tags: android, docker, macos, adb

I have a docker container on `ruby:latest` image with `android-sdk` installed.

On the host machine if I write `adb devices` I can see my physical phone listed in the devices list. It's also working in the docker container with `adb -H host.docker.internal devices`.

But the problem is when I try to install an apk, it's working on my host terminal, but not in the docker terminal (it's stuck). Is it something to configure ?

```bash
adb -H host.docker.internal install myapp.apk
# Performing Streamed Install
# ... and nothing
```

The host is a macOS on `Ventura 13.0` and an `Apple M1` chip

**Edit**: I also tested by running the container with the `--privileged` option => same behavior. Everything is working well if the host of the container is a windows machine, but I need to use the Mac

> I need to use this option because it's a gitlabrunner that trigger it and I don't want to ask for a new fingerprint each time, that's why I need to use the `-H` option, because the host already has the fingerprint.

Comment: We also encountered to this issue and for the macOS Ventura with M1 processor the solution was installation of build tools version 33.0.1, but the same version os with intel processor the issue still floats and sometimes(very rarely) helps only killing and starting adb server, hope this help you.

Comment: @Rob, thank for your feedback, but after deeling with that, we just decided to go with a Windows host